# run job in all the available computers on the pool

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have a job to run in all of the tests computers in a pool , but I don't find a way of setting an .yml to do it (dynamically, they may change and I don't want to change the .yml each time). I tried the matrix strategy and looked into the expressions and the each keyword, but nothing seems usable to do that.

I tried with the matrix strategy, but the footnote:

> The matrix syntax doesn't support automatic job scaling but you can implement similar functionality using the each keyword. For an example, see expressions.

made it for me clear that this is not going to work. Then I tried looking into the expressions and the each keyword, but there is no predefined variable or anything similar to get all the agents in a pool for iterating
I would appreciate some help.

Comment: You can use the Azure DevOps API to get all the available agents and to submit jobs to each agent. You could do this in a PowerShell script. But it's probably not a good idea. Are you trying to update test data that lives on the agent? Can you version or timestamp or hash your test data so you can easily check if it is up-to-date? Then in a build you can check and update the test data on-demand.

Comment: Oks thanks, but as far as I understood it, that is not possible with simply a .yml. 
No, I am not trying to update test data that lives in the agent, that doesn't apply, I am making hardware specific tests.

Comment: Do you have different agents representing different hardware and you need to run the tests on each type of agent?

Comment: Exactly. thats it

Comment: Are you using a [scale set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops)?